# All React app not running on my pc using npm start. Cannot resolve the error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, syntax-error

'npm' has stopped working and giving the error attached below.
Also while running any react app on my laptop using ~npm start I am getting the same error. Please help.

```
PS C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\react\portfolio> npm start
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\agentkeepalive\lib\https_agent.js:1
$→��m��mo�L�D��;�%g�?w��ŷ↓�▬��ovH0��a�5��*�ؒ��l͛�S�iy☺�r�O7����%L]��%��∟�hk
 ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\agentkeepalive\index.js:4:29)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
```

Comment: Can you add your source codes link so that we can try to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Reinstalling Worked, There was issue with npm libraries,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the `npm\node_modules\agentkeepalive\lib\https_agent.js` file used by Node's bundled npm has been corrupted. (Your hard drive may be going bad – might want to keep an eye on it, or it may be something else.)

The easiest way to fix it, since you can't run `npm` to fix `npm`, should be to just reinstall Node.js (or if there's a Repair option for it in Windows' Settings, you could try that).

Comment: Reinstalling worked! Thanks